# Booting TWRP custom recovery from SD card

Tags: twrp

I have a bootloader locked nokia 6.1 PL2 2018 and I want to temporarily boot TWRP for backup using an SD card. is it possible???

Comment: no, by-passing locked bootloader is only possible by flashing modified partition into device itself

Comment: https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/05/demystifying-android-physical-acquisition

Comment: On Android devices the physical location (offset) of the `recovery` and `boot` partitions (among many other things) is hard-coded in bootloader. You cannot make it boot from a different location, except on some development boards which provide a switch to toggle boot location.